# TLS1.2 AES 128 CBC Encrypted Data size is not a multiple of block size

Tags: aes, tls, cbc, initialization-vector, sha-1

I know that TLS ciphers such as TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA transmit data as shown https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-6.2.3.2. From my understanding the ciphertext MUST be a multiple of the block size, which in this case is 16 bytes. However when I look at the below output from wireshark, I'm confused. After subtracting the 16 bytes corresponding to the IV from the beginning of the Encrypted Application Data, that leaves 100 bytes of ciphertext which is obviously not a multiple of 16. What am I not understanding?

[image]

EDIT: I've included information about the ciphersuite

[image]

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of https://security.stackexchange.com/q/187924/. Please don't cross-post.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as it is a cross-post of https://security.stackexchange.com/q/187924/ where it already received an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The default mode of TLS use *MAC-then-Encrypt*, it compute the tag, append it to the message, and then padd it to have a length multiple of the block size (16 in our case). 
However, you can change the default mode to use *Encrypt-then-MAC* (which eliminates risks of padding attacks over AES-CBC). In this case, the message is padded and encrypted, and only then you compute the tag and add it at the end.

In your case,  TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA use SHA1, which produce a 20 bytes long tag : 
$$116-20=96=16\times 6$$

That's the only way I have to explain it, but both the server and the client have to implement the option *Encrypt-then-MAC*.

Answer (score 0):

> From my understanding the ciphertext MUST be a multiple of the block size, which in this case is 16 bytes.

That depends on what the ciphersuite is.  For CBC-mode suites, such as TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, that is the case, as padding is applied to make the 'plaintext' (which includes the MAC) a multiple of 16.  However, for AEAD-based suites, such as TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, no padding is involved, and so if the original plaintext (which, in this case, is only the protected data) was 92 bytes long, then the ciphertext would indeed be 116 bytes long.

So, are you certain that the ciphersuite is, indeed TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA?

Comment: Yes absolutely, hence my confusion.